# html <select> populated from ajax call not working on mac (safari & ff)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some different select menu in my page, when the user select the first option i call this function (and so for the other two drop down menù, same syntax but different id's and php file).

```js
function getmodello() {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/getmodello.php",
 data: {produttore: $( "#produttore-list" ).val(), lingua: '<?php echo $text_lang; ?>'},   
 success: function(data){
  $("#model-list").html(data);
 }
 });
```

and in the php file i made my query and I return some html. On windows and on my mobile phone is all working but on mac (both firefox and safari) the select doesn't get populated at all. Can someone illuminate me? Thanks

Comment: how did you meant for us to see when u're using relative path to php script in ajax request ? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax call returns empty error on Mac Safari and Chrome browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980068/jquery-ajax-call-returns-empty-error-on-mac-safari-and-chrome-browsers)

Comment: Please answer in english.

Comment: what do you spect return **data** ?

Comment: I've changed the url to http://metaweb.agency/dev/ricambi/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/getmodello.php and added this line at the top of my php script header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); but still not works. Those are three drop down menu, first for producer like mbw,vw second for the model and third for the version. The php file will return some <option>string</option> based on what the user select.

Comment: Thanks to @MHakvoort with the modification seggested it is now working :)